# Load Runner Windows Sockets program lrs_save_param parameter issue(Error Code :9005)

Tags: loadrunner, winsockets

Load Runner Windows Sockets program lrs_save_param parameter issue(Error Code :9005) is seen

In the Data.ws file i have declared the buffer as follows

```
recv RecvBuff 30
```

In **Action part** my code is as follows

```
lrs_receive("socket", "RecvBuff", LrsLastArg);
lrs_save_param("socket",LRS_LAST_RECEIVED, "param1",1,20);
lr_output_message(lr_eval_string("{param1}"));
```

The output in the LR log file is as follows

Action.c(89): lrs_receive(socket, RecvBuff)
Action.c(89): Mismatch in buffer's length (expected 30 bytes, 20 bytes actually received, difference in 10 bytes)

```
================================RECEIVED BUFFER================================
    "\x02"
    "^^^^ACK^00000133^^"
    "\x03"
===============================================================================
```

Action.c(91): lrs_save_param(socket, get_last_received_buffer, param1, 1, 20)
Action.c(91): Error : save param parameter is invalid. Error code : 9005.

Can anyone help out here please ,I need a way to validate the acknowledgement is there any other other way i can do it

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to validate the mismatch, dump the whole buffer to the screen, etc...?   Please clarify

Also, have you turned logging up to the highest levels to see if this satisfies your curiosity?

Comment: Yes i am trying to validate a mismatch i want to check if i have received a positive acknowledgement & then send the next message 
Yes i am dumping the buffer the buffer is of 20 bytes